# Cannot Create PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE in Oracle SQL Developer v19.0.1 (error: ORA-00905)

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a temporary table in Oracle SQL Developer (v.19.0.1), but it is throwing error: ORA-00905: missing keyword

```
CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE sales AS

SELECT SalesDate, Product, Quantity
FROM BI.Sales a
JOIN PRODREF.SKU b on a.item_ID = b.sku
WHERE SalesDate >= '01-JUN-19';
```

Error report -
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:
*Action:

Comment: Have you tried taking out `PRIVATE` and `TEMPORARY` individually? Also, in your sample code, you have a blank line between your `CREATE` and your `SELECT`; is your SQL Developer treating the blank line as the end of the `CREATE`? Can you reproduce the problem in SQL*Plus?

Comment: What version of the database are you connected to?  Private temporary tables are a new 18c feature.

Comment: Does it show you which line the error is at?

Answer (score 3):

Private temporary tables (PTTs) are an Oracle Database 18c feature. Oracle SQL Developer is a separate product and has its own version numbers.

So first ensure the database you're using is on this release or higher:

```
select banner from v$version;

BANNER                                                                   
Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

Next, you must prefix the name of PTTs with whatever the private_temp_table_prefix parameter is set to:

```
sho parameter private

NAME                      TYPE   VALUE    
------------------------- ------ -------- 
private_temp_table_prefix string ORA$PTT_
```

ORA$PTT_ is the default. So your create table should probably be:

```
CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ora$ptt_sales AS
  SELECT SalesDate, Product, Quantity
  FROM BI.Sales a
  JOIN PRODREF.SKU b on a.item_ID = b.sku
  WHERE SalesDate >= '01-JUN-19';
```